# Why does my WebGL application randomly crash when deployed online? (works fine on localhost, using Three.js and Chrome)

Tags: webgl, three.js

I'm creating a 3D game using Three.js. After uploading it to my website and launching Chrome to test it, it randomly crashes after some time (between several seconds and a few minutes). It's very frustrating, as all it says is "Aww snap". The developer console window is empty and there's no way to debug (atleast not that I know of).

[image: Chrome WebGL crash]

The funny thing is, everything works fine on my localhost (using xampp). 
Any idea what I am doing wrong, or how I could debug this situation?

It doesn't appear to be because of a memory leak. The webpage process stays around 100-150mb. (Even if it were, then I would have to see the same crash at my localhost)

---

**EDIT**: The error is caused by using Google's Compiler service with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS. I forgot when I upload the code the script is automatically compiled. Still strange however, as there are no errors displayed at all, just a crash occurs. I wonder why a minified script would cause WebGL to go crazy.

Comment: Or a link to the application?

Answer (score 5):

Your browser crashes because it has bugs. Generally it is responsible of the browser vendor to fix those bugs or provide workarounds. It also might be an issue with underling graphics card. There is little stackoverflow.com community can do to help you.

1. Test your code with the latest Chromium nighlites
2. Create an isolated test case where the crash be reproduced reliable manner
3. Report the bug with the test case to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list
4. Add input like suggested `chrome://gpu/` to the bug report
5. Wait that the bug gets fixed in upcoming Chrome releases - most likely if your bug report is high quality the bug gets fixed soon and the latest Chromes no longer this bug when your HTML5 game ships

Answer (score 3):

Check chrome://gpu/ it may have some clues

Comment: This helped me. Found out I had my "Hardware accelerated" setting turned off.